# Linux open file table - mode and status flags

Tags: c, linux

Referring this [link](https://man7.org/training/download/lusp_fileio_slides.pdf).

[image]

In the open file table, we have file status flags and file mode. The link states them received from `open()`.

(Referring [link](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:open)):

[image]

Is the file status in open file table the `oflags` argument in `open()` and file access mode the `mode` argument & ~umask ?

Comment: I guess it is. Maybe read the source? It is open source, you know!

Comment: The flags in the file descriptor (i.e. `f_flags` in `struct file`) are _exactly_ `O_*` derived from the the `oflags` argument. You could do: `grep -r 'f_flags.*_' .` in the kernel source top directory to see usages.